# MySql Trigger, before insert delete a row in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Is this possible? Before a row is inserted into tableA, I need to delete any rows in tableA containing duplicate data.The trigger below does not generate an error but doesn't work either.

```
CREATE TRIGGER remove_old_user
BEFORE INSERT ON userStatus
FOR EACH ROW
DELETE FROM userStatus WHERE username = NEW.username
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Is it essential that the previous record be deleted, rather than updated to match the new info? Sounds like `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` would meet most of your needs. More info in the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

(I'm assuming based on the question that the field is unique, and can be part of the primary key)